# delayed_paperclip is not hitting sidekiq

Tags: paperclip, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have set up delayed paperclip and sidekiq, however when I try the photo upload again, the log's out put is below:

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued DelayedPaperclip::Jobs::ActiveJob (Job ID: f9bf0100-2c5b-4c30-af04-9fb9b4ee8c5e) to Inline(paperclip) with arguments: "CarPhoto", 32, "image"
[ActiveJob] [DelayedPaperclip::Jobs::ActiveJob] [f9bf0100-2c5b-4c30-af04-9fb9b4ee8c5e] Performing DelayedPaperclip::Jobs::ActiveJob from Inline(paperclip) with arguments: "CarPhoto", 32, "image"
[ActiveJob] [DelayedPaperclip::Jobs::ActiveJob] [f9bf0100-2c5b-4c30-af04-9fb9b4ee8c5e]   CarPhoto Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "car_photos".* FROM "car_photos" WHERE "car_photos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 32]]
```

which indicates that Activejob is doing the job.. and on the other side in the sidekiq console, I don't see anything being logged out.. so I am wondering if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told ActiveJob to use Sidekiq so it is using the inline adapter.

```
# config/application.rb
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Be sure to have the adapter's gem in your Gemfile and follow
    # the adapter's specific installation and deployment instructions.
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  end
end
```